# Unable to locate drop down in appium using xpath /Actions class/ WebElement/JavascriptExecutor

Tags: java, appium

appium version 1.7.1
andriod java client jar 5.0.4

my code

```
 //Start APPIUM(CLI) server
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start cmd.exe /k \"appium -a  0.0.0.0 -p 4723 \"");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        URL u = new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub");
        //Give Details of ARD and App under Testing
        DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
        dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,"chrome");
        dc.setCapability("deviceName","LC4C5Y648825");
        dc.setCapability("platformName","android");
        dc.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.2");
        Thread.sleep(8000);
        //Create Driver object for AndroidDriver
        AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(u,dc);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        //driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='More options']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2500);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Create account']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2500);
        driver.findElement(By.name("FirstName")).sendKeys("****");
        driver.findElement(By.name("LastName")).sendKeys("****");
        driver.findElement(By.name("GmailAddress")).sendKeys("*********");
        driver.findElement(By.name("Passwd")).sendKeys("******");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.name("PasswdAgain")).sendKeys("******");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='android.view.View'][@text='Month']"));
        we.isDisplayed();
        we.click();[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: what are you asking?

Comment: how to click on a drop down in appium just to click to open list to select an option

Comment: Thanks Marc i am new to stackoverflow also i will follow your advice thanks once again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are opening browser and working with web application, I think you are using the **invalid locator**:
`By.xpath("//*[@class='android.view.View'][@text='Month']")`

`android.view.View` definitely looks like a class of **native app** ui element, so my guess thats the reason you can't select value in dropdown.

If you struggle with inspecting elements in mobile browser, you can use [chrome debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews)

Comment: Hi dmle thanks for the reply i tried by using  the code  {WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Month']")); we.click();   the issue is the xpath is working fine the dropdown is been highlighting but the click operation is not performing . I used Actions class , TouchAction and tried to change context also but operation is not performing ....... any suggestions to perform operation will be highly useful for my assignment Thanks buddy

Comment: I found solution thanks for your effort dmle i tried this code to locate and click on drop down and it worked from your advice i changed my xpath to {driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Month']")).click()} this xpath i used to locate drop down then for clicking on it i used {driver.switchTo().activeElement().click()}  and i got drop down list Thanks buddy